# Import Data Wizard reads wrong datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello its my first post here.
So I created a simple table in MS SQL SERVER. It contains two columns Date as date and the second column is just numbers as int.
My data is inside Excel sheet. So I try Import Wizard, then I'm checking datatypes and there is a problem because SQL reads my source column Date as datetime not a just date. And second column with numers from 1 to 100 reads as double.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you mark the columns as their expected datatypes in Excel?

Comment: As far as I remember, you can set the appropriate datatypes directly in the ImportExport Wizard

Comment: SchmitzIT yes I did